# Find a subset of columns based on another dataframe with NaN values?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm attempting to get the mean values on one data frame between certain time points that are marked as events in a second data frame.

This is a follow up to this question, where now I have missing/NaN values: [Find a subset of columns based on another dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68276507/find-a-subset-of-columns-based-on-another-dataframe)

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

 #example 
example_g = [["4/20/21 4:20", 302, 0, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN],
   ["2/17/21 9:20",135, 1, 1.4, 1.8, 2, 8, 10],
   ["2/17/21 9:20", 111, 4, 5, 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4]]
example_g_table = pd.DataFrame(example_g,columns=['Date_Time','CID', 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5])

#Example Timestamps
example_s = [["4/20/21 4:20",302,0.0, 0.2, np.NaN],
   ["2/17/21 9:20",135,0.0, 0.1, 0.4 ],
   ["2/17/21 9:20",111,0.3, 0.4, 0.5 ]]
example_s_table = pd.DataFrame(example_s,columns=['Date_Time','CID', "event_1", "event_2", "event_3"])

df = pd.merge(left=example_g_table,right=example_s_table,on=['Date_Time','CID'],how='left')

def func(df):
    event_2 = df['event_2']
    event_3 = df['event_3']
    start = event_2 + 2 # this assumes that the column called 0 will be the third (and starting at 0, it'll be the called 2), column 1 will be the third column, etc
    end = event_3 + 2 # same as above
    total = sum(df.iloc[start:end+1]) # this line is the key. It takes the sum of the values of columns in the range of start to finish
    avg = total/(end-start+1) #(end-start+1) gets the count of things in our range
    return avg

df['avg'] = df.apply(func,axis=1)

I get the following error: 
cannot do positional indexing on Index with these indexers [nan] of type float
```

I have attempted making sure that columns are floats and have tried removing the int() command within the definitions of the events.

How can I preform the same calculations as before where possible but while skipping any values that are NaN?

Comment: you can try `df['avg'] = df.fillna(0,downcast='infer').apply(func,axis=1)`

Comment: It is important that I do not mix up Na values with 0s; sometimes I have the data and sometimes I don't so I hesitate to fillna with 0...

Comment: Additionally, when I try this on my dataset, I get the following error: value should be a 'Timedelta', 'NaT', or array of those. Got 'int' instead.

Comment: In your pervious question, `example_g_table` has integer columns starting from zero, but in this question, why the columns are float values `0.0, 0.1, 0.2,..`? Does the event value 2 mean column 0.2?

Comment: @ThePyGuy-- I had made an error when writing the question. The example timestamps are now what would be matched to the floats in the example_g table

Comment: @zob, try the answer I have provided and let me know if it works for you!

Answer (score 1):

so about your question, check if this solution is ok:

```py
def func(row):
    try:
        event_2 = row['event_2']
        event_3 = row['event_3']
        start = int(event_2 + 2)
        end = int(event_3 + 2)+1
        list_row = row.tolist()[start:end]
        list_row = [x for x in list_row if x == x]
        return sum(list_row)/(end-start)
    except Exception as e:
        return np.NaN

df['avg'] = df.apply(lambda x: func(x),axis=1)
```

I  reduced the function and convert start and end parameters to integer before to the set a subset and when you call the function interows I'm using a lambda function and in Avg calculation, I remove all NaN values

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the event values are `NaN` and if any of the event value is `NaN`, just return `NaN` from the function, else return the required value.

You can also modify the function a bit to calculate the values between any two given events, i.e. not necessarily event 2, and event 3. Also, the data you provided in the previous question had event values columns as integer, but this time, you have float values like `0.1, 0.2, 0.3`, ... etc. You can just store the column for event values in a list in an increasing order to be able to access them via index values coming from events column from the second dataframe.

Additionally, you can directly use `np.mean` instead of calculating the sum and dividing it manually. The modified version of the function will look like this:

```py
eventCols = [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]  # Columns having the value for events
def getMeanValue(row, eN1=2, eN2=3):
    if pd.isna([row[f'event_{eN1}'], row[f'event_{eN2}']]).any():
        return float('nan')
    else:
        requiredEventCols =eventCols[int(row[f'event_{eN1}']):int(row[f'event_{eN2}']+1)]
        return np.mean(row[requiredEventCols])
```

Now, you can apply this function on the dataframe on `axis=1=`:

```py
df['avg'] = df.apply(getMeanValue,axis=1)

      Date_Time  CID  0.0  0.1  0.2  ...   0.5  event_1  event_2  event_3   avg
0  4/20/21 4:20  302    0  NaN  NaN  ...   NaN        0        2      NaN   NaN
1  2/17/21 9:20  135    1  1.4  1.8  ...  10.0        0        1      4.0  3.30
2  2/17/21 9:20  111    4  5.0  5.1  ...   5.4        3        4      5.0  5.35
[3 rows x 12 columns]
```

Additionally, if needed, you can also pass the two event numbers, default values are 2, and 3 which means the value will be calculated for `event_2`, and `event_3`

**Average between `event_1` and `event_2`:**

```py
df['avg'] = df.apply(getMeanValue,axis=1, eN1=1, eN2=2)

      Date_Time  CID  0.0  0.1  0.2  ...   0.5  event_1  event_2  event_3   avg
0  4/20/21 4:20  302    0  NaN  NaN  ...   NaN        0        2      NaN  0.00
1  2/17/21 9:20  135    1  1.4  1.8  ...  10.0        0        1      4.0  1.20
2  2/17/21 9:20  111    4  5.0  5.1  ...   5.4        3        4      5.0  5.25
[3 rows x 12 columns]
```

**Average between `event_1` and `event_3`:**

```py
df['avg'] = df.apply(getMeanValue,axis=1, eN1=1, eN2=3)

      Date_Time  CID  0.0  0.1  0.2  ...   0.5  event_1  event_2  event_3   avg
0  4/20/21 4:20  302    0  NaN  NaN  ...   NaN        0        2      NaN   NaN
1  2/17/21 9:20  135    1  1.4  1.8  ...  10.0        0        1      4.0  2.84
2  2/17/21 9:20  111    4  5.0  5.1  ...   5.4        3        4      5.0  5.30
[3 rows x 12 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

The format of your data is hard to work with. I would spend some time to rearrange it into a less wide format, then do the work needed.

Here is a quick example, but I did not spend any time making this readable:

```
base = example_g_table.set_index(['Date_Time','CID']).stack().to_frame()
data = example_s_table.set_index(['Date_Time','CID']).stack().reset_index().set_index(['Date_Time','CID', 0])
base['events'] = data
base = base.reset_index()
base = base.rename(columns={'level_2': 'local_index', 0: 'values'})
```

This produces a frame that looks something like this:

[image: DataFrame after some data manipulation...]

In this format calculating the result is not so hard.

```
import numpy
from functools import partial

def mean_two_events(event1, event2, columns_to_mean, df):
    
    event_1 = df['events'] == event1
    event_2 = df['events'] == event2
        
    if any(event_1) and any(event_2):
        
        return df.loc[event_1.idxmax():event_2.idxmax()][columns_to_mean].mean()
    
    else:
        
        return np.nan
    
mean_event2_and_event3 = partial(mean_two_events, 'event_2','event_3', 'values')
mean_event1_and_event3 = partial(mean_two_events, 'event_1','event_3', 'values')
    
base.groupby(['Date_Time','CID']).apply(mean_event2_and_event3).reset_index()
```

[image]

Good luck!

Edit:

Here is an alternative solution that filters out the values BEFORE the groupby.

```
base['events'] = base.groupby(['Date_Time','CID']).events.ffill()
# This caluclates all periods up until the next event. The shift makes the first values of the next event included as well.
# The problem with appoach is that more complex logic will be needed if you need to caluclate values between events that 
# are not adjasant, IE this wont work if you want the calculate between event_1 and event_3.
base['time_periods_to_include'] = ((base.events == 'event_2') | (base.groupby(['Date_Time','CID']).events.shift() == 'event_2'))

# Now we can simply do:

filtered_base = base[base['time_periods_to_include']]
filtered_base.groupby(['Date_Time','CID']).values.mean()
# The benifit is that you can now eaisaly do:
filtered_base.groupby(['Date_Time','CID']).values.rolling(5).mean()
```

Comment: thanks for your comment— one question about this is that my data frame is huge— it is over an hour of data collected at 5hz. This will cause the length to be massive as each CID will be multiplied by the number of time units. Will this approach still work well in this case?

Comment: Huge can mean anything, I cannot answer that question. Only way to figure out is to try. You can always select a sub-set of customers to begin with. But, I do not thing there is anything in my code that is not using pandas vectorized calculations, so in general it should be fast.

Comment: At the moment, this works with my example well, and working to get it working with my main dataframe that I'll be using. Could you show me how to modify this so that a rolling mean of say every 2 values per subject would be included in the columns instead of overall mean?

Comment: This is stackoverflow and not complete my work or homework for me. For this you would need to use a slightly different approach. I would try to make a boolean column with only values to include. Should be easy with the base DF and a combination of the `groupby`, `ffill`, and `shift` functions. Then just another `groupby` and `rolling(2).mean()`. Don't forget to upvote answers that are helpful for you.

Comment: I updated my answer with an alternative approach that is easier if you need to do rolling calculations! Good luck!

Comment: wow thanks very much. This has really helped me to understand what needs to go into the process. In the final two lines of your code, when using my example table, I get a key error for Date_Time, and then later when I only use CID, or when I try to use index names to grouby both columns. To make sure there aren't white spaces, I have tried df.columns = df.columns.map(str.strip). Do you have any advice about what might be causing that?

Comment: Yep, my code had the spirits needed to solve the problem, but I wrote it to quickly without checking. Made some small changes...

Comment: Thank you kindly, this was so helpful and works great in my main dataframe. And thanks for the note of caution as well about multiple different events not in sequence as well.